# SwipeRefreshLayout is only updating last Recyclerview item correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to update all my Items in a Recyclerview with the SwipeRefreshlayout,
but unfortunately will only the last item be updated, the others remain unchanged.

Here is my relevant code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //LeakCanary.install(this.getApplication());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }

    handleArrayList(getApplicationContext(), 0);
    Log.d("Arraylist", "" + intentNumber2.size());

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter();

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddReminder.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    adapter.notifyItemInserted(cards.size() - 1);

    refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

    updateRemainingTime();

    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    updateRemainingTime();
}

//refresh the time remaining on the cards
private void updateRemainingTime() {

    if (!cards.isEmpty()) {

        for (int i = cards.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Card card = cards.get(i);

            String time = card.getCardTime();
            String date = card.getCardDate();

            Date now = new Date();
            Date then = null;
            try {
                then = sdtf.parse(date + " " + time);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.d("PARSEEXCEPTION:", " " + e);
            }

            String remainingTime = calculate.calcTimeDiff(then.getTime(), now.getTime());
            Log.d("Card","Card updated " + remainingTime);
            card.cardRemainingTime(remainingTime);
            recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(i);
        }

        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    } else {
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

My Adapter:

```
    public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.ViewHolder> implements RemoveItem {

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Card card = cards.get(position);
        holder.setReminderText(card.getCardText());
        card_tv2.setText(card.getCardRemainingTime());
        holder.setSelectable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int position) {
        cards.remove(position);
        Log.d("Main", "removed " + position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, cards.size());

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

        int intentNumber = intentNumber2.get(position);
        intentNumber2.remove(position);
        Log.d("IntentNumber", "" + intentNumber);

        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), intentNumber, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmIntent.cancel();

        alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);

        File dir = getFilesDir();
        File file = new File(dir, "Reminder" + " " + position);
        boolean deleted = file.delete();

        MainActivity.handleArrayList(getApplicationContext(), 1);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends SwappingHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        public final LinearLayout background;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, RemoveItem removeItem1) {
            super(itemView, multiSelector);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            itemView.setLongClickable(true);
            removeItem = removeItem1;

            card_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_tv);
            card_tv2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_tv2);
            card_th = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            card_check = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_check);
            background = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.background);

        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (multiSelector.tapSelection(this)) {

                background.setSelected(true);

            } else {

                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                String text = "error";
                String time = "error";
                String date = "error";
                String repeat;
                boolean repeat2 = false;
                String quantity = "error";
                String mode = "error";

                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("Reminder" + " " + position);
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    text = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    time = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    date = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    repeat = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    repeat2 = repeat.equals("true");
                    quantity = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    mode = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    inputStreamReader.close();
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ChangeReminder.class);
                intent2.putExtra("POSITION", position);
                intent2.putExtra("TIME", time);
                intent2.putExtra("DATE", date);
                intent2.putExtra("TEXT", text);
                intent2.putExtra("REPEAT", repeat2);
                intent2.putExtra("QUANTITY", quantity);
                intent2.putExtra("MODE", mode);
                startActivity(intent2);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            AppCompatActivity activity = MainActivity.this;
            activity.startSupportActionMode(mDeleteMode);
            multiSelector.setSelectable(true);
            multiSelector.setSelected(this, true);
            background.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }

        public void setReminderText(String cardText) {
            card_tv.setText(cardText);

            ColorGenerator colorGenerator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
            TextDrawable drawableBuilder;
            String letter = "A";

            if (cardText != null && !cardText.isEmpty()) {
                letter = cardText.substring(0, 1);
            }

            int color = colorGenerator.getRandomColor();

            drawableBuilder = TextDrawable.builder()
                    .buildRound(letter, color);
            card_th.setImageDrawable(drawableBuilder);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Card class:

```
    public class Card implements Serializable {
public int drawable;
private String cardText;
private String cardDate;
private String cardTime;
private String cardRemainingTime;

public void cardText(String cardText) {
    this.cardText = cardText;
}

public void cardDate(String cardDate) {
    this.cardDate = cardDate;
}

public void cardTime(String cardTime) {
    this.cardTime = cardTime;
}

public void cardRemainingTime(String cardRemainingTime) {
    this.cardRemainingTime = cardRemainingTime;
}

public String getCardText() {
    return cardText;
}

public String getCardDate() {
    return cardDate;
}

public String getCardTime() {
    return cardTime;
}

public String getCardRemainingTime() {
    return cardRemainingTime;
  }
}
```

Edit:
I found out that when I reopen the app, the time correctly updates on all items.
This means there has to be a difference between calling updateRemainingTime from onRefresh and onCreate, but I don't know which. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make a change in updateRemainingTime method.

```
if (!cards.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = cards.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Card card = cards.get(i);
            String time = card.getCardTime();
            String date = card.getCardDate();

            Date now = new Date();
            Date then = null;
            try {
                then = sdtf.parse(date + " " + time);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.d("PARSEEXCEPTION:", " " + e);
            }

            String remainingTime = calculate.calcTimeDiff(then.getTime(), now.getTime());
            Log.d("Card", "Card updated " + remainingTime);
            //card.cardRemainingTime(remainingTime);
            //replaces to
            cards.get(i).cardRemainingTime(remainingTime);

        }
        List<Card> cardTemp = new ArrayList<>();
        cardTemp = cards;
        cards.clear();
        cards.addAll(cardTemp);
        recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: After implementing your code, all my items disappear. They are reappearing after reopening the app with the old time. It seems like notifyDataSetChanged is not working to refresh the items. Do you have any idea?